# ASP.NET MVC Pass Dynamic Json Data into Model to return in Partial View

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC project and I have a controller where I am getting JSON data from an external Web API.  Now I want to deserialize this JSON data and put it into a model that will eventually be passed into a Partial View.

**JSON Data:**

```
{
"results":[
{
    "name":"Company A",
    "providerName":"Company Provider A"
...(More Data Below)
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("company-info/companyinfogetapidata")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CompanyInfoGetApiData(string name, int CompanyCode, string city, string state, int zip)
    {

        /* Json Data is fetched properly */

        var json = request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

        JToken ApiData = o["results"];

       // Now I want to pass the JSON data into my model

        CompanyResultsModel getfetcheddata = new CompanyResultsModel();

       // I tried using this method below but it's not working properly

        getfetcheddata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyResultsModel>(json);

       // Pass the Model containing into the PartialView Result
        return PartialView(@"~/Views/Shared/companies/_companyResults.cshtml", getfetcheddata);

    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class CompanyResultsModel
{
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string companyProvider { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Companies.CompanyResultsModel

<p>@Model.companyName</p>
<p>@Model.companyProvider</p>
```

After I pass in the JSON data into my model, if I use this method above for displaying the data in my view, will it return all of my data properly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting? And showing the actual data your receiving would help.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The problem is none of the data is actually getting passed properly to the model.  When the partial view is returned, none of the JSON data is actually being displayed.

Comment: maybe the CompanyResultsModel's properties do not match the json struct

Comment: @aspark I made an edit above to show what the JSON data looks like.

Comment: Your data is not correct despite what you claim - you receiving a collection, not a single object. It would need to look like (for testing) `string json = @"{ 'companyName ': 'abc', 'companyProvider': 'xyz' }";` (or you need to deserialize to a model containing a property `results` which is `IEnumerable<CompanyResultsModel>`

Comment: if deserialize directly use `json` which retreived from api, you need a class like this: `class result{public List<CompanyResultsModel> Result{get;set;}}`, or deserialize use `results` string, as follows: `DeserializeObject<List<CompanyResultsModel>>(ApiData.ToString()); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json your receiving does not match your `CompanyResultsModel`. It does match a model that contains a property named `results` which is a collection of `CompanyResultsModel`.

Create the following model

```
public class JsonResultModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CompanyResultsModel> Results { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller

```
JsonResultModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResultModel>(json);
```

and if you want to return only the first `CompanyResultsModel` to the view

```
return PartialView("_companyResults", model.Results.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi - No I meant just what I said - OP is trying to serialize that json to `CompanyResultsModel` which does not match. He needs another model that does match (which is what I have shown - the `JsonResultModel`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So I just tested this code and did the following: 1) Created the `JsonResultsModel`, 2) Added the `JsonResultModel` to the controller, 3) Returned it with `return PartialView("_companyResults", model);`, 4) In my View, added `@Model Models.LoanJsonData, <p>@Model.Results</p>.`  In my view, I get the following output: `System.Collections.Generic.List1[Companies.LoanJsonModel]`

Comment: That is not what my answer states! And what is `LoanJsonData`? If that is the `JsonResultsModel` I referred to, and your returning that to the view, then `@Model.Results` is a collection of `CompanyResultsModel` so you would need to iterate through it - e.g. `@foreach { var item in Model.Results) { <p>@item.companyName</p> .... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I modified your solution a little bit but it lead me in the right direction of passing JSON data into my View.  I'm going to edit my question above soon.  Thank you so much!